# Admin area issue - Best Sellers, Most Viewed Products etc tabs on Dashboard do not update

Tags: admin

on the Dashboard within the Admin area there are some tabs on the right hand side which allow you to view Bestsellers, Most Viewed Products, New Customers etc.

The info here is completely wrong and has not changed for about a year.

If I click on the tabs, it just starts to load indefinitely and does not bring up any results.

Can anyone tell me why this would be happening and what I can do to fix it?

Many thanks

Magento 1.6

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is Magento `Report indexing issue`. So you need to **refresh the report statistics**.

For refresh statistics, follow these steps.

1. Go to Refresh Statistics pages

   ```
   Admin  >  Report  >  Refresh Statistics
   ```
2. Select all report statistics by "***tick***"ing them.
3. Then select the action `Refresh Lifetime Statistics`  and submit it.

This will resolve your issue.

Comment: what is the reason behind magento 1.9 best seller products report return blank page, reports shown, if i try to export then going to blank page, how can i export my best seller products report?@Amit